# How do you just get the vars in a url using php?

Tags: php, url, get

I have a url,

```
example.com/?/page1
```

and i want to find out what the GET part of the url is, for example:

```
?/page1
```

how do i do this? like, without having to split strings and stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following variable will contain the entirety of the query string (that is, the portion of the url following the ? character):

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

If you're curious about the rest of the contents of the $_SERVER array, they're listed in the PHP manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 2):

That is a strange GET URL because the normal format is:

`domain.com/page.html?a=1&b=2`

PHPinfo will help a whole lot:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Output of relevance:

```
<?php
// imagine URL is 'domain.com/page.html?a=1&b=2'
phpinfo();
echo $_GET['a']; // echoes '1'
echo $_GET['b']; // echoes '2'
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // echoes 'a=1&b=2'
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // echoes '/path/to/page.php?a=1&b=2'
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you want to look up [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Of course, these will 'split' the string(s) behind the scenes.

You can then use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to rebuild the query, if required.

```
 $url = "example.com/?/page1";
 $res = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
 print "Query:".$res."\n";
```

Output is:

```
Query:/page1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0, $e = count($_GET[]); $i < $e; $i++) {
    echo $_GET[$i];
}
```