# Getting vars from URL

Tags: php, url

url:

```
url.com/index.php?id=1000
```

How to get `1000` from `id` and add it into `<h1></h1>` on page?

Comment: Where does that URL come from? Please show some code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Parameters to PHP Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221136/url-parameters-to-php-variables); [How do you just get the vars in a url using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280682/how-do-you-just-get-the-vars-in-a-url-using-php); [getting variables from STRING url in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366027/getting-variables-from-string-url-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_GET`:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : FALSE;
echo '<h1>', $id, '</h1>';
```

If the URL is within a variable, use [`parse_url`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $vars);
$id = isset($vars['id']) ? (int) $vars['id'] : FALSE;
echo '<h1>', $id, '</h1>';
```

**Edit:**

If you've got [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) enabled (which is **highly** discouraged, so just for completeness), you can do this:

```
$id = isset($id) ? (int) $id : FALSE;
echo '<h1>', $id, '</h1>';
```

Normally in an application you want to de-couple from `$_GET` and wrap it into a request object:

```
class Request
{
    public function getParameter($name, $default = NULL)
    {
        return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : $default;
    }
    public function getParameterInt($name, $default = NULL)
    {            
        $value = $this->getParameter($name, NULL);
        return NULL === $value ? $default : (int) $value;
    }
}

$request = new Request();
$id = $request->getParameterInt('id');
echo '<h1>', $id, '</h1>';
```

That done, you can replace later on the request implementation with another to run and test your application with non-http requests. This also helps to better structure your code for re-usability.

Answer (score 6):

You fetch the number from the [$_GET](http://php.net/get) array and escape it with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to prevent XSS attacks:

```
echo '<h1>', htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']), '</h1>';
```

Comment: what is better `htmlspecialchars` or only `$_GET['id'];`?

Comment: Ilya, only using $_GET['id'] will make it possible for an attacker to inject HTML and Javascript into your page by adding it to the request. That way they can trick people to giving out credit card information, install viruses and so on. *Do never trust data coming from the client*. Use htmlspecialchars to prevent this.

Comment: Also - consider a missing id will result in a PHP notice : <?php echo (isset($_GET['id'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']) : 'Default H1 label'; ?>

Comment: The id is numerical, `(int)` is the [way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413425/getting-vars-from-url-php/7413701#7413701) IMHO.

Comment: hakre, you are correct that casting to an integer is correct if the number is supposed to be an integer. I didn't find that entirely obvious from the question though.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [$_GET superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) array, which holds querystring parameters.

For example:
`<h1><?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></h1>`

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the global array `$_REQUEST[]`, or in your case the explicit `$_GET`:

```
<h1><?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></h1>
```

To prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) you should also use htmlspecialchars:

```
<h1><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']); ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<h1><?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
//Perform checks on $id
echo '<h1>'.$id.'<h1/>';
```

If you wish to inject it into h1, you can echo it back and use javascript to set the innerhtml of the  tag.